# Как делать фигуры на css без прозрачных полосок

Tags: html, css

Как делать такие фигуры на CSS

```css
.hexagon {
    height: 100px;
    width: 56px;
    background: #262626;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.hexagon:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -32px;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    border-left: 32px solid #262626;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}

.hexagon:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -32px;
    border-right: 32px solid #262626;
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon"></div>
```

Чтобы не появлялись прозрачные линии - вот такие (появляются на старых версиях браузера иногда)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также эти линии всегда появляются, если просто повернуть фигуру с помощью `transform: rotate`

```css
.hexagon {
    height: 100px;
    width: 56px;
    background: #262626;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.hexagon:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -32px;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    border-left: 32px solid #262626;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}

.hexagon:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -32px;
    border-right: 32px solid #262626;
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насчёт линий при трансформации - просто добавьте translateZ(0), и линии магическим образом исчезнут:

```css
.hexagon {
    height: 100px;
    width: 56px;
    background: #262626;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translateZ(0);
}

.hexagon:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -32px;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    border-left: 32px solid #262626;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}

.hexagon:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -32px;
    border-right: 32px solid #262626;
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon"></div>
```

А вот насчёт старых браузеров точно не скажу. Возможно, это тоже поможет.

Comment: Магия, да и только!